# Troubleshooting Vite Environment Variable Import Error

Tags: variables, environment-variables, vite

.env.local file:
VITE_API_KEY:XXXXXXXX

fetchNetflixOriginals: `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/tv?api_key=${import.meta.env.VITE_API_KEY}&with_networks=123`,

Error:
GET https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/tv?api_key=undefined&with_networks=123 401 (Unauthorized)

The env varaible is undefined. I have used it as mentioned in the docs. Does there is a need to config vite.config.js file?